# Image rotating in HTML - not wanted

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this very simple code in my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p><b>XYZ</b>, blah blah blah </p>
            </div>

            <div>
                <img src="IMG_5584.jpg" height="15%" />
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>

</html>
```

When I run this in Chrome, the picture loads up rotated 90 degrees.  I opened this in Windows Explorer, and it is the right way up, and I have loaded the image in in Chrome (via ctrl-O), and it comes the right way up. Any idea why its rotating like that?

Comment: well, for starters, your height attribute is malformed. It should be height="15%".

Comment: Can you please explain? I'm new to HTML

Comment: There is nothing in the code provided that would cause an image to rotate. There must be some other code at work here. Can you reproduce the problem in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or link to your page?

Comment: Fixed that - still rotating the image.

Comment: can you perhaps create a test case so we can see the problem reproduced? The code in your question, assuming a fixed `height` attribute, will definitely not rotate an image.

Comment: Does the image contain metadata from the camera which says to rotate the image when it is loaded? Try opening it in an image editor, then re-saving for web use without the metadata which could be miss-understood by different browsers.

Comment: Fire up the image in an image viewer like irfanview, and see if it has the "autorotate" flag set. If so, the image in the browser is actually correct, that's how the pixels are orirented. Windows actually rotates the image for you, despite the pixel order

Comment: Now if only high-end photo-processing software AND windows would simply support lossless jpg rotation (which is easy) we wouldn't need such a (stupid) flag.. Meanwhile this thing helps users from screwing up their original images just by rotating them.

Comment: Thanks for that all.  Any suggestions on free img editors?

Comment: @keynesiancross The default editors for your OS are good. Paint for Windows and Photo Editor for iOS

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was an issue with the metadata in the img.  I had to open it in an editor, as the comments above suggested, rotate it and save it.